# Haskell error when creating List comprehension

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm following this [guide](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension) to create a list comprehension.

```
data Value = Two|Three|Four|Five|Six|Seven|Eight|Nine|Ten|J|Q|K|A
          deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum)

data Suite = Hearts | Spades | Diamonds | Clubs
         deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum)

type Card  = (Value, Suite)

pack :: [Card]
pack = [(Value,Suite) | Value <- [Two .. A], Suite <- [Hearts .. Clubs]]
```

When I create the pack function it always throws

`error: Data constructor not in scope: Suite :: Suite`

Comment: Variable names must begin with a lower case letter.

Comment: By the way, the word you're looking for is "suit". A suite is a set of rooms, a set of musical compositions, or probably since other things (none of them related to what you mean).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
pack :: [Card]
pack = [(Value,Suite) | Value <- [Two .. A], Suite <- [Hearts .. Clubs]]
```

The left hand side of `<-` should be a variable (or a pattern w/ variables in it). In Haskell those start with a lowercase letter. Try this:

```
pack :: [Card]
pack = [(value,suite) | value <- [Two .. A], suite <- [Hearts .. Clubs]]
```

Comment: It's correct to say that the left-hand side of `<-` is a (refutable) pattern; a variable by itself *is* a valid pattern.

Comment: You should look up the definition of the word "or" instead of trying to be pedantic. >:(